# C# запущенный процесс не может создать файл

Tags: c#

Программа на C# запускает программу на C++ которая должна создать файл и закрыться.

```
Process proc = new Process();
proc.StartInfo.FileName = WorkDirRak + "\\" + "s.exe";
proc.StartInfo.Arguments = $"{IP} {Name} {Pass} {Pass}";
proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
proc.Start();
```

Я добавил:

```
proc.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = WorkDirRak + "\\";
```

Теперь у меня работает, а у других нет. Файл просто не появляется.

Весь код:

```
Process proc = new Process();
proc.StartInfo.FileName = WorkDirRak + "\\" + "s.exe";
proc.StartInfo.Arguments = $"{IP} {Name} {Pass} {Pass}";
proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
proc.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = WorkDirRak + "\\";
proc.Start();          
proc.WaitForExit();        
ans = File.ReadAllText(WorkDirRak + "\\" + "Result.r");
```

Comment: А где "у других" лежит запускаемое приложение? Вполне возможно, что у этих пользователей просто нет прав на запись в указанной директории.

Comment: Лежит,главное приложение запускается от админа.

Comment: А s.exe выбрасывает какие-то исключения или пишет что-то в лог? Может быть в Event Viewer'е есть какая-то ошибка?

Comment: Нет,файл тупо не появляется.

Comment: Ну, вы же программист? Ответьте себе на вопрос: а запускается приложение вообще, или нет? То, что файл не создаётся, не означает автоматом, что приложение не запускается. Выясните для начала это.

Comment: Не запускайте с сетевого диска, выведите путь запуска в мессаге бокс на тех компьютерах, на которых не запускается... Прояснится многое.